# Kotlin How can I call extension function

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to call an extension function from MainActivity class in another class. 
How can i do this?

```
object MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val StringBuilder.readHistory: StringBuilder
    get() {
        val temp = this@readHistory
        temp.setLength(0)
        try {
            val file = InputStreamReader(MainActivity.openFileInput(MainActivity.getString(R.string.dosyaadı)))
            val br = BufferedReader(file)
            var line = br.readLine()
            while (line != null) {
                temp.append(line + "\n")
                line = br.readLine()
            }
            br.close()
            file.close()
} catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return temp
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call this outside of the class, because it's nested inside this class and therefore only applies to that scope.

Make the extension property top-level (move it outside of the class).

Comment: when i outside it I'm getting this error 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wB6n-FwOJFW6H44eoG0Qfs55KxzZhBM2/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

[Member extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members) are only visible within the class that they're declared in. However, you can place your extension function outside your class to be able to import and use it anywhere else.

Comment: When I outside it I'm getting this error https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wB6n-FwOJFW6H44eoG0Qfs55KxzZhBM2/view

Comment: Please post this as text, and potentially as a separate question - there's no doubt that functions can be placed outside classes, this seems to be an issue specific to your code. Looking at it, for example, your `Activity` should definitely not be an `object`.

Comment: https://github.com/hakkikaancaliskan/NetHesap/tree/newSettingsActivity here's my whole code. Could you please check it?